# TypeError on Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am using `read_csv` in Pandas

```
data = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, sep=None, decimal='.')
```

and gives me back this error

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 398, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

It is very strange because, according to Pandas documentation, this is supposed to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv):

> sepstr, default ‘,’
>
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can, meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'.

For some strange reason, it was not using automatically Python parser engine. Setting the right `sep` parameter solved for me.